# Gitlab Python API - attribute for date of shared project

Tags: python, api, date, gitlab

Do you know, whether in Gitlab there is an attribute that can be accessed via the Python API for the date when a project was shared with a group? It is not the attribute `created_at`, as the project exists way longer before it was shared. I am looking for this date:

[image: Gitlab group GUI with shared project]
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The date you've highlighted there is the project's last activity date. Not the date the project was shared. The last activity attribute is `.last_activity_at`. If you want to see the date access was granted in the UI, it's in the members page of the project.

If you want the date a project was shared with the group using the python-gitlab library, you can use the [audit events API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html).

```py
group = gl.groups.get(GROUP_ID)

for event in group.audit_events.list(as_list=False):
    if event.details.get('add') == 'project_access':
        print(
            f'Access granted for project "{event.details["target_details"]}" '
            f'to "{group.name}" group at {event.created_at} '
            f'by {e.details["author_name"]}.'
        )
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working for me. I assume the reason is that audit events are a Premium plan GitLab feature, and I only use the free plan.

Comment: @Zozzoy unfortunately then I don't think this capability is available in the API unless you have the Premium feature. I'm guessing you may only be able to see this information in the UI in the members list.